# KnockoutJS : assigning a new model to and existing one e.g (model.order = neworder) does not change the values in the view, why?

Tags: knockout.js

I have this knockout model which has an observable object with alot of properties

```
model.object{}
```

instead of changing the properieties individually like this:

```
model.object.property1("cool");
```

i decided to reassing it to a new object

```
model.object = new object;
```

when i checked the console, it updated the exististing model object, but then the binding in the view

```
<span class="ml-1" data-bind="text:object.property1">10</span>
```

did not change.

why is this ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the code `ko.applyBindings()` had already bound the object to the html, and it happens only once. The binding is lost if you do `model.object = new object;`.

If you want to update the entire object in one line, you can try using the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(objectWithSamePropertiesAndNewValues, model.object);
```

Comment: If you could provide a fiddle I can check it out.

Comment: that might be too long, but i solved it by making the  model.object and observable.  so instead of assigning it like this model.object = new object , i can now do model.object(new object), and it worked flawlessly